# UITableViewController with custom data source not showing cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I currently have a UITableViewController that sets up a custom data source in its init function:

```
class BookmarkTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var date: Date

  // MARK: - Init
  init(date: Date, fetchAtLoad: Bool) {
    self.date = date
    super.init(style: .plain)
    self.tableView.dataSource = BookmarkDataSource(date: date)
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
  }

// ...
}
```

The custom data source is as follows:

```
class BookmarkDataSource: NSObject {
  let date: Date

  init(date: Date) {
    self.date = date
    super.init()
  }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension BookmarkDataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test content"

    return cell
  }
}
```

However when I run on the simulator or on a device nothing shows up in the table view. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Note: I'm using Xcode 8.0 Beta and Swift 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store a strong reference to your BookmarkDataSource object. The dataSource of tableView becomes nil with the code you posted.

```
class BookmarkTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var date: Date
    var dataSource:BookmarkDataSource

    // MARK: - Init
    init(date: Date, fetchAtLoad: Bool) {
        self.date = date
        super.init(style: .plain)
        dataSource = BookmarkDataSource(date: date)
        self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is it. Thanks!

Comment: I botched the dataSource variable creation but you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think your cells aren't being properly instantiated.

Try replacing

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: This is also extremely important to do, in order to reduce memory consumption and actually take advantage of UITableView. 
However that is not the reason for the data not showing up